# SlidingTabLayout With NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am going to handle navigation drawer with sliding tabs using following Library called ObservableScrollView
https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView. The following are the xml and java files which I used to display.

My XML file:

```
<com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.TouchInterceptionFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
        <com.para.paraservice.widgets.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fr_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" -->

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
                android:name="com.para.paraservice.widgets.NavigationDrawerFragment"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/flexible_space_image_height"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.TouchInterceptionFrameLayout>
```

My Java code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;
import com.para.paraservice.BaseActivity;
import com.para.paraservice.R;
import com.para.paraservice.ViewPagerTab2ScrollViewFragment;
import com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollViewCallbacks;
import com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.CacheFragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.ScrollState;
import com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.ScrollUtils;
import com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.Scrollable;
import com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview.TouchInterceptionFrameLayout;
import com.para.paraservice.widgets.NavigationDrawerCallbacks;
import com.para.paraservice.widgets.NavigationDrawerFragment;
import com.para.paraservice.widgets.SlidingTabLayout;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class LandingActivity extends BaseActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks,
            NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private View mToolbarView;
        private TouchInterceptionFrameLayout mInterceptionLayout;
        private ViewPager mPager;
        private NavigationAdapter mPagerAdapter;
        private int mSlop;
        private boolean mScrolled;
        private ScrollState mLastScrollState;
        private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.landing);

            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            mToolbarView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PARA");
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

            ViewCompat.setElevation(findViewById(R.id.header), getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
            mPagerAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

            final int tabHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tab_height);
            findViewById(R.id.pager_wrapper).setPadding(0, getActionBarSize() + tabHeight, 0, 0);

            SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
            slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_indicator, android.R.id.text1);
            slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
            slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
            slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);

            ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
            mInterceptionLayout = (TouchInterceptionFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
            mInterceptionLayout.setScrollInterceptionListener(mInterceptionListener);


            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer,
                    (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);

        }
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownMotionEvent() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
            if (!mScrolled) {
                // This event can be used only when TouchInterceptionFrameLayout
                // doesn't handle the consecutive events.
                adjustToolbar(scrollState);
            }
        }

        private TouchInterceptionFrameLayout.TouchInterceptionListener mInterceptionListener = new TouchInterceptionFrameLayout.TouchInterceptionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev, boolean moving, float diffX, float diffY) {
                if (!mScrolled && mSlop < Math.abs(diffX) && Math.abs(diffY) < Math.abs(diffX)) {
                    // Horizontal scroll is maybe handled by ViewPager
                    return false;
                }

                Scrollable scrollable = getCurrentScrollable();
                if (scrollable == null) {
                    mScrolled = false;
                    return false;
                }

                // If interceptionLayout can move, it should intercept.
                // And once it begins to move, horizontal scroll shouldn't work any longer.
                int toolbarHeight = mToolbarView.getHeight();
                int translationY = (int) ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout);
                boolean scrollingUp = 0 < diffY;
                boolean scrollingDown = diffY < 0;
                if (scrollingUp) {
                    if (translationY < 0) {
                        mScrolled = true;
                        mLastScrollState = ScrollState.UP;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else if (scrollingDown) {
                    if (-toolbarHeight < translationY) {
                        mScrolled = true;
                        mLastScrollState = ScrollState.DOWN;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                mScrolled = false;
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDownMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMoveMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev, float diffX, float diffY) {
                float translationY = ScrollUtils.getFloat(ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout) + diffY, -mToolbarView.getHeight(), 0);
                ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout, translationY);
                if (translationY < 0) {
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mInterceptionLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.height = (int) (-translationY + getScreenHeight());
                    mInterceptionLayout.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                mScrolled = false;
                adjustToolbar(mLastScrollState);
            }
        };

        private Scrollable getCurrentScrollable() {
            Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment();
            if (fragment == null) {
                return null;
            }
            View view = fragment.getView();
            if (view == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (Scrollable) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        }

        private void adjustToolbar(ScrollState scrollState) {
            int toolbarHeight = mToolbarView.getHeight();
            final Scrollable scrollable = getCurrentScrollable();
            if (scrollable == null) {
                return;
            }
            int scrollY = scrollable.getCurrentScrollY();
            if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
                showToolbar();
            } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
                if (toolbarHeight <= scrollY) {
                    hideToolbar();
                } else {
                    showToolbar();
                }
            } else if (!toolbarIsShown() && !toolbarIsHidden()) {
                // Toolbar is moving but doesn't know which to move:
                // you can change this to hideToolbar()
                showToolbar();
            }
        }

        private Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
            return mPagerAdapter.getItemAt(mPager.getCurrentItem());
        }

        private boolean toolbarIsShown() {
            return ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout) == 0;
        }

        private boolean toolbarIsHidden() {
            return ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout) == -mToolbarView.getHeight();
        }

        private void showToolbar() {
            animateToolbar(0);
        }

        private void hideToolbar() {
            animateToolbar(-mToolbarView.getHeight());
        }

        private void animateToolbar(final float toY) {
            float layoutTranslationY = ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout);
            if (layoutTranslationY != toY) {
                ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout), toY).setDuration(200);
                animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        float translationY = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout, translationY);
                        if (translationY < 0) {
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mInterceptionLayout.getLayoutParams();
                            lp.height = (int) (-translationY + getScreenHeight());
                            mInterceptionLayout.requestLayout();
                        }
                    }
                });
                animator.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
            else
                super.onBackPressed();
        }

         /**
         * This adapter provides two types of fragments as an example.
         * {@linkplain #createItem(int)} should be modified if you use this example for your app.
         */
        private static class NavigationAdapter extends CacheFragmentStatePagerAdapter {

            private static final String[] TITLES = new String[]{"Applepie", "Butter Cookie", "Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean", "KitKat", "Lollipop"};

            public NavigationAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            protected Fragment createItem(int position) {
                Fragment f;
                final int pattern = position % 5;
                switch (pattern) {
                    case 0:
                        f = new ViewPagerTab2ScrollViewFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
    //                    f = new ViewPagerTab2ListViewFragment();
                        f = new ViewPagerTab2ScrollViewFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
    //                    f = new ViewPagerTab2RecyclerViewFragment();
                        f = new ViewPagerTab2ScrollViewFragment();
                        break;
                    case 3:
    //                    f = new ViewPagerTab2GridViewFragment();
                        f = new ViewPagerTab2ScrollViewFragment();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                    default:
                        f = new ViewPagerTab2ScrollViewFragment();
    //                    f = new ViewPagerTab2WebViewFragment();
                        break;
                }
                return f;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return TITLES.length;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return TITLES[position];
            }
        }

    }
```

So the sliding tab functionality working fine without Navigation Drawer.When i add navigation drawer layout to xml and java code to LandingActivity sliding tabs with view pager not working.Can you please tell me what exactly i am doing wrong here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using both drawer and tabs in same activity? Or make different fragment and use tabs in it.

Comment: Thanks Harry for quick response.I want the drawer layout on top the tabs like play store.so i am trying to achieve like that.but unfortunately i am getting this problem.i will try with different fragment and get back.

Comment: I tried it many ways.but I am not getting to work out.please give some advice's or some examples.so that i can check it out and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find **ViewPagerTabListViewActivity.class** and it layout **layout/activity_viewpagertab.xml** in ObservableScrollView samples

**EDIT:** Edited layout and class
activity_viewpagertab.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <!--<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->

        <!--
    Padding for ViewPager must be set outside the ViewPager itself
    because with padding, EdgeEffect of ViewPager become strange.
    -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/tab_height"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
                    app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />

                <com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
                    android:background="@color/primary" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.samples.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

part of ViewPagerTabListViewActivity.class

```
public class ViewPagerTabListViewActivity extends BaseActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks, NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private View mHeaderView;
private View mToolbarView;
private int mBaseTranslationY;
private ViewPager mPager;
private NavigationAdapter mPagerAdapter;

private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpagertab);

    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

    mHeaderView = findViewById(R.id.header);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(mHeaderView, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
    mToolbarView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mPagerAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_indicator, android.R.id.text1);
    slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
    slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);

    // When the page is selected, other fragments' scrollY should be adjusted
    // according to the toolbar status(shown/hidden)
    slidingTabLayout.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            propagateToolbarState(toolbarIsShown());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
        }
    });

    propagateToolbarState(toolbarIsShown());

    //Added this --------------------------------------------

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), (Toolbar) mToolbarView);
}

//Added this -----------------------------------------

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now it works like a charm, shared a screenshot. Glad to work on your problem thanks.

[image: ToolBarWithTabs]

Comment: make copy of ViewPagerTabListViewActivity.class and copy navigation drawer code in it as I haven't used <com.para.paraservice.observablescrollview> in layout so it might cause error in your file.

Comment: I just commented that code and used only navigation drawer code.but it is not displaying tabs and navigation drawer also not working as expected.

Comment: Hey bro, just did it for you. Check the Edit.

Comment: Harry thanks for your help.If you don't mind can you tell me what is propagateToolbarState method here.I think here you haven't declared.Can you tell me plzzz.

Comment: If you find this class "ViewPagerTabListViewActivity" in samples I have added two comments -//Added here- where I have added my code (not altered other code in that class) and i works, do the same. And my job was to make it work, to know more you need to look into the library for propagateToolbarState() code. Use ''ctrl+click' on function.

Comment: Yes got it Harry.Thanks for your help.Now the things are working fine as expected.And one more thing i observed is,the tab sliding or scrolling from viewpager is not that much of smooth.

Comment: One more thing how can we display navigation drawer below of the toolbar when we scrollup.Now it is displaying with cutting some part of the navigation drawer.Can you help out for this please..

Comment: Dont do that because toolbar is showing and hiding, drawer is initialized with same top padding at staring point so better use full screen drawer and its also proper according to material design specs.

Comment: Thanks harry thanks for your suggestion.I will put it same as it is.If anything need help regarding this concept i will ask you furthur.