# NavigationDrawer with SlidingTabs

Tags: android

I want to use SlidingTabs and NavigationDrawer, like e.g. in Google Play. I implemented from tutorials both, but when I click on elements in NavigationDrawer  I want to change SlidingTabs with new tabs and fragments. Any tutorials or feedbacks?

Comment: what you need are multiple fragments

Comment: see my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532083/slidingtablayout-with-navigationdrawer/29536832#29536832) in similar question, used [ObservableListView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView), vote up if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer.
I have been using this for quite sometime now and it works pretty well.

Comment: can you tell me how can i dynamically add drawer items? in my case , i want to load items to the drawer based on the parameter i'm passing. can you help me?

Comment: Using the `Drawer.Result` object that essentially what you get after calling `drawer.build` has method `addITem()` in overloaded form. Refer to https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/fde00e5573310384b90d1f7f92d2b45c2ed8a2ba/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.java

Also there are other useful methods such as `removeItem`, removeAll` and `updateItem`.

Comment: i cant able to understand it. Bro can you please give me any working example code if possible? actually my requirement is, based on the gmail account configured on the device , i want to load drawer menu items. say for example three items for person A, 7 for person B, 4 for person D,.. like this.. can you help me bro?

Comment: or else can you please tell me how can i add a expantablelistview or listview to the slidingmenu?

Answer (score 1):

You can visit the following links for implementing NavigationDrawer with SlidingTabs using fragments in your application

https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip

http://www.paulusworld.com/technical/android-navigationdrawer-sliding-tabs